# List of lists (inner lists being deleted or memory released)

Tags: c, list, memory

I use a network simulator, OPNET, based around C. In one of my C files (known as a process model) I have a globally accessible linked list (called obstacle_list). In the code below I fill it with smaller lists containing strings. This seems to work fine and I can read back the overall list at the end.

However I need to access this global list of lists from another C file (process model) at a later point.

When I try to access this global linked list, I can see it hold 380 items (correct) but when I try to access the inner linked lists they’re empty.

It must be a memory allocation oversight when I am populating the lists first day. As I create the inner lists using the line “input = op_prg_list_create()” and allocate memory for the content of the list using strdup I don’t see why this would occur.

I’m very stuck on this, so any help or pointers as to what could possibly be happened would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

```
fgets(line, sizeof(line), obstaclePositions_traj_file);

obstacle_list = op_prg_list_create();

while (line != OPC_NIL) 
{
token = strtok(line, "\t\n"); //Pull the string apart into tokens using the \t
input = op_prg_list_create();

while (token != NULL)
       {
          test_token = strdup(token);

          if (op_prg_list_size(input) == 0)
           op_prg_list_insert(input,test_token,OPC_LISTPOS_HEAD);
          else
           op_prg_list_insert(input,test_token,OPC_LISTPOS_TAIL);
      token = strtok (NULL, "\t\n");
      }     

       if (op_prg_list_size(obstacle_list) == 0)
    op_prg_list_insert(obstacle_list,input,OPC_LISTPOS_HEAD);
   else
    op_prg_list_insert(obstacle_list,input,OPC_LISTPOS_TAIL);

}


//check the list has been populated correctly below (it has)

/*size_ob_list = op_prg_list_size (obstacle_list);
for (k = 0; k <size_ob_list; k++)
{
line_coord_list = (List*)op_prg_list_access (obstacle_list, k);     
count_inner_list = op_prg_list_size (line_coord_list);
for (j=0; j< count_inner_list; j++)
{
    coords = (char*)op_prg_list_access (line_coord_list, j);
    printf("%c", coords);       
}
}*/
```

Answer (score 0):

`while (line != OPC_NIL) {}` is suspect.

On EOF, fgets() **returns** null, but **does not alter** the buffer (the contents of the last succesfull call will still be in there)

```
obstacle_list = op_prg_list_create();

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), obstaclePositions_traj_file) )
{
    input = op_prg_list_create();

    for( token = strtok(line, "\t\n"); token ; token = strtok (NULL, "\t\n") )
       {
          test_token = strdup(token);

          op_prg_list_insert(input,test_token
            , (op_prg_list_size(input)==0) ? OPC_LISTPOS_HEAD : OPC_LISTPOS_TAIL
            );
    }     

    op_prg_list_insert(obstacle_list,input
     , (op_prg_list_size(obstacle_list) == 0) ? OPC_LISTPOS_HEAD : OPC_LISTPOS_TAIL
     );

}
```

Comment: Hi Wildplasser,Thanks for your help. I have tested it out but it only seems to insert one string per inner list. My file will contain a list of strings: 203.14,123.25 followed by a tab followed by another number pair. The amount of number pairs per line varies. The solution above only loops the for loop once. I tried changing the middle condition from token to sizeof(line) but it appears that "line" changes to contents of the token with the line "token=strtok(line,"\t\n");". Any ideas?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to remove your first read-ahead strtok() call (before the loop). Fixed it.

Comment: It's working now (much tidier than my first solution so thank you) but unfortunately it doesn't solve the original problem! When I try to access this from another C process model the inner lists are empty (but it can see size=380 in the global obstacle_list). The only think I can think of is that obstacle_list is defined as "List* obstacle_list;" in a global header file. Perhaps I should actuallycreate the list in the header file (using op_prg_list_create())? Or maybe the inner lists need to be global also?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot comment on code I don't know. The op_prg_list_isert() for instance. Or de declarations/definitions/typedefs of your variables. My crystal ball is down for maintenance at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far anyway. It made my code more efficient anyway

Comment: BTW: the selection between OPC_LISTPOS_HEAD and OPC_LISTPOS_TAIL is probably not needed. For an empty list inserting at the head == inserting at the tail. I would also suggest to put a few printf()s inside the loop to see how the tokeniser works (could be a space in the token stream for instance. Or a '\r' )